# Is there a difference between a slow cooker and a crock pot?

Tags: equipment, slow-cooking, crockpot

What is the difference between a crock pot and slow cooker? Both terms seem to be used for the same thing.  Is this correct?  Are they the same?  Or is there some key difference between them?

Answer (score 20):

Crock-Pot is a brand name.  Slow cooker is the generic term.

It's like Kleenex & tissue or for the Brits, Hoover & vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

crock-pot is a American brand-name
slo-cooker is a British brand-name

Comment: "slo-cooker" may be a brand name for a generic 'slow cooker', it just happens to be that the British chose a brand name much closer to the generic.

Answer (score 0):

"Crock-pot" has become a genericized brand name; any brand of slow cooker can be called a crock-pot, even though Crock-Pot is a specific brand. For more examples, see wikipedia's [list of genericized brand names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks).

Answer (score -1):

All crock-pots are slow cookers (in the USA), but all slow cookers are not crock-pots. For instance, I inherited a slow cooker from my mother that is essentially a non-stick casserole with a lid that sits on a separate warming unit not unlike an electric griddle. It's pretty useless for cooking, but a decent service unit.

EDIT: Obviously, it is marketed as a slow cooker. Equally obviously, it's not a crock-pot. Down-votes without explanation are very annoying. http://www.target.com/p/west-bend-oblong-slow-cooker-with-tote/-/A-10646883?ref=tgt_adv_XSG10001&AFID=Google_PLA_df&LNM=|10646883&CPNG=Appliances&kpid=10646883&LID=PA&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=10646883&gclid=CIXhr9TbhroCFYk9QgodURQAUg

THIS is a crock-pot: http://www.target.com/p/crock-pot-stainless-steel-slow-cooker-5-qt/-/A-10963122?ref=tgt_adv_XSG10001&AFID=Google_PLA_df&LNM=|10963122&CPNG=Appliances&kpid=10963122&LID=PA&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=10963122&gclid=CI_Ln_CUh7oCFQeCQgoddgIAoQ

Comment: That is the same device being talked about. It's just designed to be removed from the heating element for transport. Mine does that too, though it's shaped a bit different.

Comment: @Yamikuronue talked about where?? The question asked about the difference between crock-pot and slow cooker. I gave an example of a slow cooker that is decidedly NOT a crock-pot. And now I've been down voted twice?

Comment: One of the benefits of a "crock pot" is that it heats from the sides as well as the bottom. My slow cooker obviously heats only from the bottom and in no way resembles a crock-pot.

Comment: Plus a crock-pot is insulated all around. My *not-a-crock-pot* is not.

Comment: *The term slow cooker is the generic product name for a stand-alone appliance with a heating element and ceramic casserole dish that cooks foods with slow, moist heat.* As I suspected! My appliance doesn't even really meet the standard for *slow cooker* (although it is marketed as such), much less *crock-pot*.

Comment: I will grant you this: I wouldn't call it either one. But if it's a slow-cooker, it's a crock-pot, in my book. I was accepting your premise that it was considered a slow-cooker for some reason

Comment: It could have something to do with what it calls itself, "West Bend Oblong Slow Cooker with Tote". Is a 30lb roaster a Crock-pot too?